# Flutter - How to set initial value in multiselect dropdown?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, multi-select

```dart
Widget _buildEquipmentCategoriesDropdown() {
  return Column(
    //
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(text: 'Equipment Categories: ', style: Styles.blackBold16, children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: '*',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: ColorsValue.orangeColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
      Dimens.boxHeight5,
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: const Offset(
                5.0,
                5.0,
              ),
              blurRadius: 5.0,
              spreadRadius: 1.0,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: ColorsValue.whiteColor,
              offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
              blurRadius: 0.0,
              spreadRadius: 0.0,
            ),
          ],
          color: ColorsValue.whiteColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: //
            Obx(
          () => MultiSelectDialogField(
            initialValue:
                //
                controller.selectedEquipmentCategoryList,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border()),
            buttonIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            items: controller.equipmentCategoryList
                .map(
                  (equipmentCategory) => MultiSelectItem(
                    equipmentCategory?.id,
                    equipmentCategory?.name ?? '',
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onConfirm: (selectedOptionsList) => {controller.equipmentCategoriesSelected(selectedOptionsList)},
            chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Dimens.boxHeight20,
    ],
  );
}
```

Controller:

```dart
Future<void> getInventoryCategoryList(String? facilityId) async {
  //// SEE HERE, THE DATA TYPE FOR BOTH THE LIST AND THE INITIAL VALUE IS THE SAME

  equipmentCategoryList.value = <InventoryCategoryModel>[];
  selectedEquipmentCategoryList.value = <InventoryCategoryModel>[];
  selectedEquipmentCategoryNameList.value = <String>[];
  //
  final _equipmentCategoryList = await editJobPresenter.getInventoryCategoryList(
    isLoading: true,
  );
  if (_equipmentCategoryList != null) {
    for (var equimentCategory in _equipmentCategoryList) {
      equipmentCategoryList.add(equimentCategory);
    }
    //selectedEquipmentCategoryList = equipmentCategoryList;
    if (jobDetailsModel.value?.equipmentCatList != null)
      for (var equipCat in jobDetailsModel.value?.equipmentCatList ?? []) {
        InventoryCategoryModel equipmentCategory = InventoryCategoryModel(
          id: equipCat.equipmentCatId,
          name: equipCat.equipmentCatName,
        );

        selectedEquipmentCategoryList.add(equipmentCategory);
        print(selectedEquipmentCategoryList[0]);
        selectedEquipmentCategoryNameList.add(equipmentCategory.name);
      }
  }
}
```

I want to have certain values pre-filled in the multiselect, the widget just won't do it.
The data for the list (initial values) comes from an API and then the UI gets updated (using Getx).

Comment: can you include full sample widget

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the select element can be set by using the 'selected' attribute on the required option. This is a boolean attribute. The option that is having the 'selected' attribute will be displayed by default on the dropdown list

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a MultiSelectDialogField in Flutter, you can set an initial value that is pre-selected when the dialog opens. To set this initial value, you need to provide a list of items that you want to be selected initially.

In the given code, the initialValue parameter of the MultiSelectDialogField is set to [controller.selectedEquipmentCategoryList]. This means that the list of selected equipment categories stored in the controller.selectedEquipmentCategoryList variable will be used as the initial value for the dropdown.

So when the user opens the dropdown, the items in the controller.selectedEquipmentCategoryList will already be selected, and the user can add or remove other items as desired.

Comment: MultiSelectDialogField does not appear to have a controller parameter. What do you mean?

I did however find a parameter called `initialValue` that can be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are also confusing Rx as an ObserVER vs. ObservABLE. Rx is an observable, i.e. you watch it for changes using Obx or GetX widgets, (I guess you can call these two widgets "Observers".)

### Example

```
    class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Controller c = Get.put(Controller());

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
         
                Obx(
              () => MultiSelectDialogField(
                initialValue: 
                    //
                    c.selectedEquipmentCategoryList,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border()),
                buttonIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                items: c.equipmentCategoryList
                    .map(
                      (equipmentCategory) => MultiSelectItem(
                        equipmentCategory?.id,
                        equipmentCategory?.name ?? '',
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                onConfirm: (selectedOptionsList) =>
                c.update_selected(selectedOptionsList),
                  
                chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(),
              ),
            ),
          
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Controller extends GetxController {
 List equipmentCategoryList= [].obs
List selectedEquipmentCategoryList = [].obs;
  void update_selected(List selectedOptionsList) =>'your code (update equipmentCategoryList)';
}
```

Comment: I hope I conveyed my problem correctly. I can select the options and they show up as chips in the multiselect all fine. It's the initial value that I cannot set. Meaning, when the screen loads, I need certain values (chips) to be already selected and showing (as chips) in the multiselect.

Comment: I think it's work also for you want,and don't forget to make initial value is part of all values for any condtions.

Comment: Means? I don't understand what you are saying. I tried setting a hard-coded value like ["abc"] as the initial value, even that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe because the type of data that's came from API don't match to initialValue parameter,try to cast

Comment: To finish this ️ use The Debugger.

Comment: Please check the updated code. I have added the controller code. I am already casting it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope below answer will help you. you should use `GetBuilder` instead of Obx and you must initialize controller call Api using load controller.
in this example, i am ignoring your predefined decoration variable and colors,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/multi_select_flutter.dart';

import 'MultipleController.dart';

class buldMultiFormUsingApi extends StatefulWidget {
  const buldMultiFormUsingApi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<buldMultiFormUsingApi> createState() => _buldMultiFormUsingApiState();
}

class _buldMultiFormUsingApiState extends State<buldMultiFormUsingApi> {
  final Controller controller = Get.put(Controller());

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller.loadequipment();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(//
            children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(text: 'Equipment Categories: ', children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: '*',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  offset: const Offset(
                    5.0,
                    5.0,
                  ),
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                  spreadRadius: 1.0,
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                  blurRadius: 0.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            ),
            child: //
                GetBuilder<Controller>(builder: (controller) {
              return MultiSelectDialogField(
                initialValue: controller.selectedEquipmentCategoryList,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border()),
                buttonIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                items: controller.equipmentCategoryList
                    .map(
                      (equipmentCategory) => MultiSelectItem(
                        equipmentCategory?.id,
                        equipmentCategory?.name ?? '',
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                onConfirm: (selectedOptionsList) {
             // write code on your selected equipment
                },
                chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Controller code is below

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Controller extends GetxController {
  List equipmentCategoryList = [].obs;
  List selectedEquipmentCategoryList = [].obs;

  Future loadequipment() async {
    // here ApiRequest.getequipmentCategory() call api to load equipment category
equipmentCategoryList=await ApiRequest.loadEquipment();

update();

  }
}
```

if you want equipment category should load first, you dont want to show empty list then call  `controller.loadequipment();` it on splash screen or home screen.

Answer (score 0):

your init(selected) List and List from APi maybe the same values but they have different **InventoryCategoryModel** object instances so that can possibly be causing the problem with the **==(equality)** check of the **InventoryCategoryModel model**.

```
class InventoryCategoryModel {
      final String id;
      final String name;
      InventoryCategoryModel({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
      });
    
      @override
      bool operator ==(Object other) {
        if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    
        return other is InventoryCategoryModel && other.id == id;
      }
    }
```

try to adding this override for == operator in your model.